# Error using horzcat, dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and I have the following code.

```
   a=randi([1,121]);
   c=randi([1,121]);
   if a~=c
      b=randi([1,q.get(a)]);
      d=randi([1,q.get(c)]);
      if a~=d & b~=c & b~=d & (B(a,c)+B(a,d)+B(b,c)+B(b,d)==0)
         B(a,d)=0;
         B(c,d)=0;
         B(a,c)=1;
         B(b,d)=1;
      end
   end
```

I got the titled error. Any comment will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Edit: Here B is a sparse matrices of size 121*121.

Edit2: q is an arraylist. I got it as follows:

```
Import java.util.LinkedList
q=LinkedList();
```

Comment: You need to tell us what `q` is.

Comment: It looks like `q.get` does not return a number (1x1 array) here. If you check what it returns, you can probably figure out the error as well.